# Adding to dynamic variable variable array

Tags: php, arrays, oop

In my class, I have a public variable:

`public $full_rows = array("text");`

I want to be able to add to that array, like so:

`$form->addarray("full_rows", array("url","name"));`

So I have this function:

```
public function addarray($arrayname, $array = array()) {
    array_merge($this->$arrayname, $array);     
}
```

Except it's not affecting the array `full_rows` at all.  Why not?

**Edit**
Thanks to roullie for the correct answer.  Turns out I'd forgotten that `array_merge` returns the merged array rather than just doing it.  I thought it was a problem with variable variables (as I'd never used them before).

Here is my final function:

```
public function addarray($arrayname, $array = array()) {
    if((isset($this->$arrayname)) && (is_array($array))) {
        $this->{$arrayname} = array_merge($this->{$arrayname}, $array);
    } else {
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Comment: `$form->addarray($form->full_rows, array("url","name"));` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the value of the merged array to your `$full_rows`

```
public function addarray($arrayname, $array = array()) {
    $this->$arrayname = array_merge($this->$arrayname, $array);     
}
```

Comment: Aah, I screwed up on array_merge.  Thank you! But can you tell me why I couldnt write this: `$this->$arrayname[] = "foo";` ?

Comment: Aah I figured it out.  It needs to be: `$this->{$arrayname}[] = "foo";`